# How to set a context variable in a template

Tags: angular

I want my page to be dependent on a model object which is emitted from an Observable. If the object were a list, I'd use

```
<div ngFor="let currentListItem of myObservable | async" >
```

however, `ngFor` is not applicable, since I don't have a list of models, but just one. Is there something like

```
<div ngContext="let currentItem of myObservable |async" >
```

which would allow me to access currentItem's properties like this

```
<div ngContext="let currentItem of myObservable |async" > 
     <label>{{currentItem.name}}
</div>
```

Comment: ... What's the question? And what's `ngContext`?

Comment: ngContext is a sample of attribute that I am looking for. Basically, something that will expose a variable inside the div

Comment: See if it's what you're looking for: `<div *ngIf="myObservable | async as currentItem"><p>{{currentItem.name}}</p></div>`

Comment: I guess it could work, but seems unweildly. I don't need IF, it should always display...

Comment: Well, you **must** do some kind of logic to handle this, because your variable actually is an `Observable`, you don't have it *synchronously*.. That said, you can do in another way (using safe navigation operator): `<div>{{(myObservable | async)?.name}}</div>`

Comment: well yea, I was hoping to bind it like with ngIf, but having only the `let` part, without the `ngIf` part. Is there no no-op structural directive, just for binding.

By the way, what do you call the `as currentItem` as a verb? Casting? Assigning? Exposing? Binding?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145829/discussion-between-f-khantsis-and-developer033).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `as` keyword with `*ngIf*` in Angular 4:

```
<div *ngIf="myObservable | async as currentItem">
     <label>The current item's name is {{currentItem.name}}</label>
</div>
```

> I guess it could work, but seems unweildly. I don't need IF, it should always display...

Well, that's the only way to do what you want. There is no harm in the `*ngIf`; it will prevent the text I've added (*The current item's name is*) from displaying until the observable emits, which is presumably what you want anyway.